# Apache + Tumblr Custom Domain

Tags: apache-2.2, cname-record

Have searcehed high and low for answer to this, but haven't found one.

Problem: I want to use a subdomain (blog.archivism.ca) of my domain (archivism.ca) as my tumblr custom domain.

I created the CNAME record and it is successfully pointing to domains.tumblr.com as it should. However, when I visit the url (blog.archivism.ca) tumblr spits out a "not found" error. MXLookup shows that while the cname is correct, http for that domain is not resolving. From my googling, I've discovered that the DNS side of things is handle by the dns record I created, I still need to handle the http side of things. I just don't know how to do this with Apache, and everything I've read doesn't seem to address this specific problem. I just created a new file in /sites-available/ with the following info, but it is still not working:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blog.archivism.ca
ServerAlias domains.tumblr.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Amypme have any idea where to go next? I assume that I don't need to specifiy the document root as that's irrelevant to tumblr.

Answer (score 1):

Your DNS looks OK, and since web clients will follow the CNAME directly to domains.tumblr.com, the Apache httpd configuration you reference is irrelevant and should be removed.

Your DNS SOA record suggests you've made 3 changes today (serial 2013010703), and also indicates a Time-to-Live (TTL) of 43200 seconds.   It's possible that tumblr.com performed a lookup of your blog.* site before the current CNAME record was in place, and their servers will likely cache incorrect (or negative) results for the full TTL of 12 hours.

[tumblr.com documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_domains) indicates their end of the setup may take up to 72 hours to complete.  I don't have any insight into their business processes, but that seems like quite a while.

So, my recommendation is to wait for 12-24 hours and see how things look.  I suspect you'll find your site to be functional.  If not, double-check the hostnames you entered into the Tumblr custom setup page.

Comment: The cname was working earlier today before I started messing with it. I changed it to an a-record to see if that would resolve the problem. I've since changed it back. I'll leave it for 3-4 days and see what happens.

Comment: Consider this resolved, I was way over-thinking it. AGT was right, everything was fine. Problem was fixed by disabling the custom domain on tumblr and then reenabling it. It's now resolving for me correctly. FML.